# what is the best method to filter a collection by type?

Tags: scala

What is the best method to filter a collection by type ?
**I want that the resulting type is the filtered one.**
I found two possibile syntaxes, what is the better ?

```
val list = List(1,"two",3,"four")

//1) using "Typed" helper object

object Typed { def unapply[A](a: A) = Some(a) }

val list1 = for {
  Typed(i: Int) <- list
} yield i


//2) using flatMap

val list2 = lo.flatMap {
    case i: Int => List(i)
    case _ => Nil
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `collect`

```
list.collect {
  case a: Int => a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't remember `collect`, using `filter` instead of `flatMap` should still be shorter & faster:

```
val list2 = lo.filter {
    case i: Int => true
    case _ => false
}.asInstanceOf[List[Int]]
```

If we don't pretend as if pattern matching does something significantly different than doing an `isInstanceOf`, we can also do just this:

```
val list2 = lo.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).asInstanceOf[List[Int]]
```

That's not very idiomatic, though... pamu's solution is definitely more elegant.

Comment: using filter the result type is not the filtered one

Comment: @frhack Indeed, it inferred the wrong type. Updated. It's not the most elegant solution, though... But if everything is already a `List[Any]`, there is no much type safety to rescue anyway. I'll leave it here, because it might be slightly more performant.